# ORDER BY FIELD(orderNum, 1,2,0) in Zend Framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, sql-order-by

I have following query

```
SELECT id, fName, orderNum FROM tTable ORDER BY FIELD(orderNum, 1,2,0)
```

I would like to sort `orderNum` field and display records in order like values in orderNum field 1,2,3 should come first and rest of `0` values rows must be come after.

Is there any solution? I'm implementing this in Zend Framework, so please if possible in

```
->order(????) format
```

Any help will be heartily appreciated. I searched everywhere in google but not get it solved :(

Comment: Where exacly is a problem? Creating a query in Zend `$select = $db->select()->from('tTable', array('id','fName, orderNum'))->order('FIELD(orderNum, 1,2,0)');` or query is not producing correct results?

Comment: Yes @Volvox, query was not creating correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no SQL expert so maybe you can do it better, but it might be enough for you:

```
SELECT id, fName, orderNum
FROM tTable
ORDER BY IF(orderNum > 0, orderNum, (select max(orderNum) from tTable)+1) ASC
```

Or (dirty but faster):

```
SELECT id, fName, orderNum
FROM tTable
ORDER BY
  CASE orderNum
    WHEN 0 THEN orderNum+2147483646
    ELSE orderNum
  END
```